# How can I sanitize json output from thymeleaf template?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am generating json from a thymeleaf template. I would like to sanitize the output before its returned to the client. I've tried a `@ControllerAdvice` but it wasn't invoked. I also tried an interceptor but struggled to sanitize the response body and put it back in again.

thanks

Comment: Please add some sample code. Also, by output do you mean sending json from the server to the client with an AJAX request. A bit unclear.

Comment: an AJAX request is getting the data.

Comment: Are you using Jackson to convert your object to json string when returning from controller.

Comment: No, my `@Controller` invokes a thymeleaf template that generates json.

Answer (score 1):

> Use `@RestController` instead.

It will do serialization for you, therefore there is no need for you to sanitize JSON. It is also a best practice in creating RESTful APIs.

Comment: yeah, it's a hybrid approach for legacy reasons. There's a predetermined format for the javascript to comprehend, I don't want to build it out as objects in java.